# Mapbox - Continent borders geo codes needed

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, mapbox

I want to make a clickable map with Mapbox. When I zoom out very much, I want to see the continent borders (instead of the countries') and the continents that are clickable.
The main problem is, that I do not find continent border geocodes.

An alternative idea was to aggregate the country layers, but I have no idea how to do that with Mapbox.

I have the country-geocodes like this:
"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Aruba"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-69.899,12.452],[-70.066,12.547],[-70.035,12.614],[-69.973,12.568],[-69.899,12.452]]]},"id":"ABW"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Antigua"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-61.716,17.037],[-61.86,17.013],[-61.887,17.098],[-61.817,17.169],[-61.686,17.098],[-61.716,17.037]]]},"id":"ATG"},....

Anyone can help? :(

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with Mapbox. If you can't find the correct GeoJSON collection on the web, you can create one yourself. You can merge multiple features from a GeoJSON collection into one feature with the right tools. QGIS for example. With QGIS you can easily select features, merge them into one and save it as a new GeoJSON collection.

QGIS website: http://www.qgis.org/en/site/

Thematic tutorial: http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/06/merging-polygons-in-qgis.html